# Where to start as frontend WPF / Xaml developer

Tags: wpf, xaml, frontend, blend

What should custom controls and even to change some application styles when it comes to, for example, change the thumb of a slider or add multiple thumbs to the slider bar. In web development, people usually have a guy 
I have 1 year of experience working with WPF, but it still looks hard for me when it comes to custom stuff.
 dependency properties.

Comment: caliburn.micro: http://caliburnmicro.com/ trust me, it is the way WPF should be used. then combine it with Fody and Fody.PropertyChanged https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion to be a good "Frontend" `WPF` developer there are some key concepts that you should master, I may mention :

**1 First of all :**

- [XAML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752059(v=vs.100).aspx)

**2 Second of all :**

- [Styles.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970773(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Resources.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms750613(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Logical/Visual Tree.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms753391(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Dependency Properties.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx)
- [Animation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752312(v=vs.100).aspx)
- [Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.trigger(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [VisualStateManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)
- *Optional :* Learn how to manipulate [Blend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj171012.aspx)

**3 Learning a good `architectural design pattern` :**

- [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx) : here you have multiple choices, you can :

  - Go on your own : and MVVM your applications alone.
    or
  - Choose some 3rd party helper libraries such as : [MVVMLight](http://www.mvvmlight.net/), [Caliburn](http://caliburnmicro.com/).
    or
  - [PRISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) for large complex lob apps (can be used for simple apps too though)

---

Concerning your own controls, there are two options :

- [Custom Controls](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/07/writing-reusable-custom-control-in-wpf.html)
- [User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol(v=vs.110).aspx)

As you are going to use `XAML` most of the time, XAML as any other programming language has it own right way of doing things, it has its own patterns, I strongly advice you to take this [Pluralsight course called XAML Patterns](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/xaml-patterns/table-of-contents) course, this will help you understand more WPF and XAML and know exactly the spirit of this technology

Comment: I'll put some time extra in XAML and try to get really good on it. Untill now I was treating XAML as something like HTML, but I can see it's way more powerful. Every time I need to customize something I see myself hitting my head to the wall.

Comment: Check this one, I think they have good topics on XAML: https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541?l=cWn0dxwqB_4305632527

Comment: @Dom : Indeed, XAML is almost the most powerfull markup language, and yes :) that video series is great from bob tabor, I just finished it this afternoon, definitely recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to adhere to the MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel) design when it comes to creating a good WPF application. Its specific intent is to separate the view and and model (data) concerns.

The easiest way to follow MVVM in WPF is to use [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/) and [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

If you want to see what a complex application looks like caliburn.micro. have a look at the code for the [gemini framework](https://github.com/tgjones/gemini).

In short; MVVM is the way to use WPF, Fody automatically deals with INotifyPropertyChanged, and Caliburn Micro makes MVVM very easy to implement.

Comment: I have no problems on how WPF and MVVM works, my problem is when I need to do anything related to frontend. I'm somehow "frontend impaired". My place is in the codebehind world, but with the need in the market for full stack developers. I need to effort myself.

Comment: fair enough; personally, I bailed and switched to HTML/CSS; Guy that made caliburn is making this: http://aurelia.io/ its delightful. :D